# climbing ladder in pygame does not work due to gravity and collisions

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to add to my game a collision so that once the player is colliding with the ladder and the speed for the y axis (which is controlled by gravity) is more than 0 (which means gravity is being used). But the problem I am having is that once I try to use the ladder the collision never seems to happen and if it does sometimes happen the gravity gets in the way and pulls downwards. The other problem is that I cannot figure out where I would add a collision to check if the player is not longer colliding with the ladder meaning you are on one of the platforms

I have tried to check for collisions by making the console print True if it is happening but that seemed to only work when I was on the left side of the ladder.

```
class Ladder(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, pic):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y
        super().__init__()
        self.picture = pic
        self.picture = pygame.transform.scale(self.picture, (50, 440))
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()

class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, pic_one):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y
        self.speed_y = 0
        self.speed_x = 0 
        self.GRAVITY = 0.9
        self.picture = pic_one
        self.permission_to_jump = True
        self.on_ground = True
        self.picture = pygame.transform.scale(self.picture, (100, 100))
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.xpos
        self.rect.y = self.ypos

    def update(self):
        if self.on_ground == False:
            if self.picture == self.picture_one:
                self.GRAVITY = 0.9

            self.xpos += self.speed_x 
            self.ypos += self.speed_y
            self.speed_y += self.GRAVITY  # Accelerate downwards.
            self.rect.x = self.xpos
            self.rect.y = self.ypos

            if self.ypos >= 620:
                self.ypos = 620
                self.speed_y = 0
                self.on_ground = True



        if self.on_ground == True:
            self.speed_y = 0
            self.xpos += self.speed_x 
            self.ypos += self.speed_y




    def jump(self):
        if self.permission_to_jump == True:
            if self.on_ground:
                #pygame.mixer.Channel(1).play(pygame.mixer.Sound("C:/sounds/Jump Sound Effect.wav"))
                self.on_ground = False
                self.speed_y = -25#Makes you move upwards






    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))

    def is_collided_with(self, sprite):
        return self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect)


player_one = Player(400, 200, player_one_first_pic)
ladder = Ladder(120, 130, ladder_picture)
while True:
    [...]



if joystick.get_button(0) and player_one.is_collided_with(ladder) and player_one.speed_y >= 0:
                    player_one.on_ground = False
                    player_one.speed_y = -4

player_one.update()

player_one.draw()
```

The result is that the player's gravity stops the climbing the ladder working and that the player can only slightly climb the ladder when its touching the left of the ladder and the player cannot even climb the ladder

Here is a diagram if you do not fully understand my code (Sorry if its slightly confused I found it difficult to put into a diagram)
[image: diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see from you code, you add the gravity whenever your character is not on the ground. Which is correct but not complete.
You should add further checks and avoid to add gravity when you are on a ladder for example.

Here a mere example to give you the idea, far from being a working update of your code.

```
def update(self):
    if self.on_ground == False:
        if self.picture == self.picture_one:
            self.GRAVITY = 0.9

        self.xpos += self.speed_x 
        self.ypos += self.speed_y
        if not self.on_ladder:
            self.speed_y += self.GRAVITY  # Accelerate downwards.
        self.rect.x = self.xpos
        self.rect.y = self.ypos
```

So you may add an `on_ladder` attribute to player and switch it from `True` to `False` in the main loop.

```
player_one.on_ladder = player_one.is_collided_with(ladder)
```

A similar reasoning should be done when the player is on a floating platform.